# Xamarin.Forms Update Label Text From a Service

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a Label on MainPage.xaml. I can edit Label Text from MainPage.xaml.cs.
There is a foregroung service running as well. There is function in this service to check a value from SQLite DB for every 10 secs. When value changes, Label text should be updated. I tried binding but it is a bit confusing. I manage updating by using like this: (foreground service timer changes App.SomeValue)

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{ 
  lblSyncID.Text = App.SomeValue;
}
```

But I need to see changes without OnAppearing or any other navigation change.

---

EDIT:
With @Jason's suggestion I used Messaging Center (and also binding) and it works now:

**MainPage.xaml:**

```
<Label Text="{Binding AppWaitingRecordValue}" ...
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    private string appWaitingRecordValue;
    public string AppWaitingRecordValue
    {
        get { return appWaitingRecordValue; }
        set
        {
            appWaitingRecordValue = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppWaitingRecordValue));
        }
    }
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        BindingContext = this;

        AppWaitingRecordValue = "0";

        MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App>((App)Application.Current, "AppRecord", (sender) =>
        {
            AppWaitingRecordValue = App.recordWaiting.ToString();
        });
    }
    .
    .
```

**TimestampService.cs (from Project.Android):**

```
// get i from DB
App.recordWaiting = i;
Xamarin.Forms.MessagingCenter.Send<App>((App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "AppRecord");
```

Comment: this is what databinding is for.  You bind the value of the Label to a property in your model, then you update your model from your service.

Comment: yes, it seems to be the best option but I couldn't figure out binding from another namespace (label is on namespace Project11 but timestamp service is on namespace Project11.Droid)

Comment: if you are trying to communicate between an Android service and a Forms page that are in separate projects, then you should use MessagingService